# Consultar datos ana ruta php desde un servidor de node.js

Tags: php, nodejs, express, socket.io

Tengo un backen en php que consula a una base de datos, y tengo otro en express que maneja los sockets, la idea es que mi app se comunique a una ruta express o al evento de sockets y este haga una petición a otro servido con php, ejemplo:

```
router.post('/tareas', (req, res)=>{
   //codigo que consulta a la direccion http://loquesea.con/tareas.php
   res.send(//datos obtenidos de la consulta)
})`
con sockets 
`tareas(data){
   sockets.on()//codigo que consulta a la direccion http://loquesea.con/tareas.php
   sockets.emit('evento',//datos obtenidos de la consulta)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la libreria de `axios` o el de node `fetch`

instalacion:
`npm i axios` o `yarn add axios`

```
const axios = require('axios')

// más codigo ....

router.post('/tareas', (req, res)=>{
   //codigo que consulta a la direccion 

   axios.get('http://loquesea.con/tareas.php')
    .then( res => {

      res.send( res.data )

    })

})
```

Comment: Gracias, osea que axios tambien se puede utilizar desde una ruta de express?, pense que solo se podia usar desde app de frontend.

Comment: Si, por supuesto, desde el servidor puedes hacer peticiones a otros servidores sin ningún problema. asi es como funcionan los bots.

Comment: muchas gracias si funcionó, pero ahora tengo un asunto, no se como recibir datos con php ya que en el backend no puedo usar FormData(), axios.post('http://loquesea.con/tareas.php',datos) donde datos es un objeto que tiene usuario y contraseña... es para logear un usuario

Comment: al enviar los datos a /tareas usas req.body (tienes que usar body-parser en tu node), despues usas axios.post('loquesea.con/tareas.php', req.body) y con eso llega los datos a tu php.